# R get substring from dataframe with another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing cities name and another containing part of cities (sometimes), cities, and region. I would like to extract the cities from this string using the other dataframe.

I'll illustrate using this example:

`df1 <- data.frame(c( "Baroy"  ,     "Iligan City", "Lala",    "Kapatagan",    "Solano",      "Molave"   ))`

`df <-data.frame(c("Solano, Nueva Vizcaya", "Baroy, Lanao del Norte","Baroy, Lanao del Norte","Kapatagan, Lanao del Norte","Maranding Lala Lanao del Norte" ,"Molave, Zamboanga del Sur","Iligan City Lanao del Norte"))`

I would like to get:

```
1   Solano, Nueva Vizcaya              Solano
2   Baroy, Lanao del Norte             Baroy
3   Baroy, Lanao del Norte             Baroy
4   Kapatagan, Lanao del Norte         Kaptagan
5   Maranding Lala Lanao del Norte     Lala
6   Molave, Zamboanga del Sur          Molave
7   Iligan City Lanao del Norte        Iligan City
```

Comment: Have you always a comma separing city from region?

Comment: @BBrill, no I don't always have this pattern, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(df1[,1], 
       function(x) data.frame(Col1=grep(x, df[,1], value=T),Col2=x)))
#                              Col1        Col2
#  1         Baroy, Lanao del Norte       Baroy
#  2         Baroy, Lanao del Norte       Baroy
#  3    Iligan City Lanao del Norte Iligan City
#  4 Maranding Lala Lanao del Norte        Lala
#  5     Kapatagan, Lanao del Norte   Kapatagan
#  6          Solano, Nueva Vizcaya      Solano
#  7      Molave, Zamboanga del Sur      Molave
```

Suppose if elements present in `df1` are not in `df`

```
  dfNew <- df[-7,,drop=F]
 do.call(rbind,lapply(df1[,1], function(x){
      Col1=grep(x, dfNew[,1], value=T); if(length(Col1)>0) data.frame(Col1=Col1, Col2=x)}))
```

Comment: Yes, this is the idea I also had: Grep the name of the city in the larger strings. This works.

Comment: @martin. One of the city `kapatagan/kaptagan` seems like a typo?

Comment: well, it isn't in the cities list anyway ;), but probably, yes

Comment: @akrun thanks for the answer. How would you side step the situation where an element is present in df1 but not in df. This yield this yield this error, Error in data.frame(Col1 = grep(x, df[, 1], value = T), Col2 = x) :  
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Comment: @DJJ, You could do `do.call(rbind,lapply(df1[,1], function(x) {Col1=grep(x, df[,1], value=T); if(length(Col1)>0) data.frame(Col1=Col1, Col2=x)}))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach without `lapply`.

```
# create a regex pattern
pattern <- paste0(".*(", paste(df1[[1]], collapse = "|"), ").*")
# [1] ".*(Baroy|Iligan City|Lala|Kapatagan|Solano|Molave).*"

# match pattern and create a data frame
dat <- data.frame(region = df[[1]], city = sub(pattern, "\\1", df[[1]]))
```

The result (`dat`):

```
                          region        city
1          Solano, Nueva Vizcaya      Solano
2         Baroy, Lanao del Norte       Baroy
3         Baroy, Lanao del Norte       Baroy
4     Kapatagan, Lanao del Norte   Kapatagan
5 Maranding Lala Lanao del Norte        Lala
6      Molave, Zamboanga del Sur      Molave
7    Iligan City Lanao del Norte Iligan City
```